# Install pycharm snap package

Tags: snap, pycharm

I am new to snap packages and all. I want to install 'pycharm community' snap package when I'm having a problem while using `sudo install pycharm-community snap` it says `install: cannot stat 'pycharm-community': No such file or directory`
what should I do ?

Answer (score 5):

you should install it by typing `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`